# Confused by move semantics of struct fields inside a Box

Tags: rust

If I do the following, I get an error:

```
struct A;
struct B;

fn consume_a(_a: A) {}
fn consume_b(_b: B) {}

struct C(A, B);

impl C {
    fn foo(self: Self) {
        consume_a(self.0);
        consume_b(self.1);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c = Box::new(C(A, B));

    // Consume internals
    let _a = c.0;
    let _b = c.1;
}
```

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `c`
  --> src/main.rs:21:9
   |
20 |     let _a = c.0;
   |         -- value moved here
21 |     let _b = c.1;
   |         ^^ value used here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `c.0` has type `A`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I can achieve the same thing (consumption of internals) doing this:

```
fn main() {
    let c = Box::new(C(A, B));
    c.foo();
}
```

The way it works above (`c.foo()`) means that I have moved out of boxed content; how can this happen? None of the API's in `Box`'s documentation show I can obtain the contained value as a type (i.e. all methods return `&T` or `&mut T` but not `T`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in the method, moving out of a struct's field directly works fine, but moving out of a field of a struct that's in a `Box` will first move out of the `Box` into a temporary variable and then move out of the field of that temporary. Thus when you try to move out of the second field, the `Box` has already been destroyed and there's just a temporary left that you can't use.

You can make this work by creating the temporary yourself:

```
let c2 = *c;
let _a = c2.0;
let _b = c2.1;
```

Comment: But `*c` should yeild either `&C` or `&mut C` no ? Then how is `let _a = c2.0;` even allowed ? That is also one of my questions.

Comment: `Box` is special. If you dereference a `Box` you get the inner value. There's no way yet to implement this for your own types, but there's an RFC for it: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1646

Comment: ah ok. Sorry for being further confused, but if `let c2 = *c;` moves out of `Box` to create a temporary as you said, how does it work if it were a `Box` of a `trait` - i mean how does compiler know the size to allocate on stack for that temporary ?

Comment: That obviously won't work, but it's not necessary to work, since you can't move out of a trait object in general.

Comment: right - so you mean it's something like compiler keeping a track of whether it's a `Box` of a trait object or a concrete object somewhere and using that metadata to determine what should the behavior/result of `*c` be ? (btw is this documented somewhere - it would spare you the trouble of explaining :-)

Comment: Actually the Compiler doesn't really track anything, it knows the type, and if you try to deref a `Box<T>` but `T` doesn't implement [`Sized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sized.html), then the deref can only be one that creates a `&T` or `&mut T`. If I had found the docs to this I'd have posted it in the answer, but sadly I can't find anything anywhere. This probably stems from the fact that `Box` didn't always exist in Rust, but it was a builtin pointer type with the `~` sigil

Comment: ah right - nw - your explanations did clear up many doubts i had. So next time i see something a little unexpected with `Box` i'll probably think it's a special handling by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Your original code works when *non-lexical lifetimes* are enabled:

```
#![feature(nll)]

struct A;
struct B;

fn consume_a(_a: A) {}
fn consume_b(_b: B) {}

struct C(A, B);

impl C {
    fn foo(self: Self) {
        consume_a(self.0);
        consume_b(self.1);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c = Box::new(C(A, B));

    // Consume internals
    let _a = c.0;
    let _b = c.1;
}
```

This indicates that the original failure was simply a weakness of the borrow-checker.